# Multiple slashes in qoutes - PHP

Tags: php

What is the correct way to escape a slash in PHP?

My Current code is this:

```
   $url_loc = '/test/'.$event_title_lowercase;
```

my IDE shows me that the '/test/' inside the `$url_loc` is wrong.
Would be the correct way to fix this issue be to add a backslash before the first slash of the '/test/'?

So it would look like this:

```
   $url_loc = '\/test/'.$event_title_lowercase;
```

The reason for asking this is because Atom is showing me this differently to the line above:
[image]

Comment: you're not in double quotes, thus, the current code is fine syntax wise

Comment: @OmarAbbas Why?

Comment: What is the reason given? If `$url_loc` was used in a regex with `/` as the delimiter it would cause an issue, that's the only issue I'd see.

Comment: *my IDE shows me that the '/test/' inside the $url_loc is wrong* - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @NigelRen it shows me the text differently. I added a screenshot to this question.

Comment: Atom is wrong. This is not a PHP issue. Forward slashes have no special context unless being used as delimiters. https://3v4l.org/k1Flb Maybe your doctype is not PHP?

Comment: @user3783243 my doctype is PHP. I will open a bug report to Atom.